# Update Records in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using Visual Studio 2008 for creating a Winforms app. I have connected a database to it called XStats. There is one table in it called XGames and in that table 2 fields, `XIndex` (the primary key field) and `GameNumber`. Using the following code I can add records to the database, the data is taken from a text box, but once added I cannot view them unless I shut down the app and restart it.

```
con.ConnectionString = connectionString

con.Open()

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO XGames (GameNumber) VALUES ('" + TextBox701.Text + "')"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

con.Close()
```

The existing records in the database are displayed on the form in detailed view via a binding navigator. How can I make it so that I can view all the records in the database, even those that are added during the current session. As will be obvious, this is my first attempt at creating and using a database with a win forms app, so all and any help is most welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how you would refresh the control. Just a comment though that you should use parameterised queries.

Comment: It sounds like there is also a form with 701 unnamed text boxes on it. Maintenance will be fun.

Comment: No lol no form with 701 textboxes on it, its just a sandbox of a form that I use for learning. When I feel I have grasped the principles of the technique only then do I build it into my current app.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple answer to this question. 
In short you could poll the db (setting maybe a timer) to see if there are new records.

/There are better options that writing SQL code directly in a string, built on the fly; but this is another story.

Answer (score 0):

See [SqlDependency Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx). Requires SQL Server Service Broker

[Query Notifications in SQL Server (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Do you update the control when u press the button to insert a item? if not this could be a start. (Call the update method of the control u use to display the items in, at the end of the Button_Click event.)

What I usually did a year back, was to keep a seperate list in my code with al items of the database in it, and when an item is inserted to the db, its added to the list as well. Therefore u can check beforehand if an item is already in the database, and reject it before an SQL statement is executed. (yes i know, not the best way to program, but we have to begin somewhere and learn.)